# How can I sum the rows of Matrix ignoring the first line? In C

Tags: c, matrix, vector, struct

I did the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamLinhas; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tamColunas; j++) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            vetormedia[j] = (informacoes[i][j] + informacoes[i][j]) / tamVetor;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to record in an array the result of the sum of the matrix's rows but I need to ignore the first line of the Matrix.

In a nutshell, the values of the first line cannot be included in the sum. I just cannot get it done right. I've been trying for hours...

Comment: To bypass the first line do "for (int i = **1**; i < tamLinhas; i++) { ..." . Also remove the useless test "if (i >= 0)"

Comment: Out of that "vetormedia[j] = (informacoes[i][j] + informacoes[i][j]) / tamVetor;" is *very*strange

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out a way to resolve that line of code as well... I gotta sort of reset the values after moving on to the next row I guess... I'm confused, not thinking clearly this online class is making me so anxious. Not getting an explanation from the professor is a real problem... At least for me.

Comment: I put an answer trying to understand what you want

Answer (score 1):

To bypass the first line of the matrix *informacoes* just start the iteration at the index 1 rather than 0:

```
for (int i = 1; i < tamLinhas; i++) {
```

Note your test *if (i >= 0)* is useless even in your initial case because *i* cannot be negative

That line is very strange :

> ```
> vetormedia[j] = (informacoes[i][j] + informacoes[i][j]) / tamVetor;
> ```

because you do not sum the rows and you save that value in the same place for all the lines.

To just sum the rows of each line separately and save the result in *vetormedia* :

```
for (int i = 1; i < tamLinhas; i++) {
  int sum = 0
  for (int j = 0; j < tamColunas; j++) {
    sum += informacoes[i][j];
  }
  vetormedia[i] = sum;
}
```

Supposing *tamLinhas* values 3 and *tamColunas* values 4 and *informacoes* is the following matrix :

```
1 2 3 4
4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1
```

after the previous loop *vetormedia* will be :

```
x 22 18
```

where "x" design any value because the first line of the matrix is bypassed

Do you want that ?